# how to increase the chances for a professor to participate in a conference?

Tags: conference, invitations

In my current place of work, we are organizing a conference, and we would like it to have continuity over time. Because we are a young career in CS and this is our first congress we are having troubles to find keynote speakers and professors that would like to be in charge of the different tracks of the conference. Our university has agreed that they will pay the charges of the speakers related to plane tickets and accommodation if it applies. I would like to start sending invitations, and the question is what to put on them to increase the possibility of having a positive answer from them?
Thanks

Comment: If you really cover the expenses, you should be able to attract people. If you also offer to arrange the flights, and hotels, and thus reduce the hassle of your invitees, this is an additional plus.

Comment: Target potential speakers known by academics at your university and get an academic that knows the potential speaker to invite them. The academic will know how to phrase the invitation to increase the possibility of acceptance.